# Recursive types in OCaml?

Tags: recursion, types, ocaml

Hi this is my first time posting on Stack Overflow and I've run into a problem while trying to construct a type in OCaml

I'm trying to construct a type tree that has nodes/leafs/etc. This is what I have so far.

```
type ('a, 'b) tree = Empty | Leaf of 'b | Node of ('a * tree) | ....
```

My node is supposed to be a type that contains the its name and another tree as a tuple.  But when I tried to compile this it said tree required two arguments. So I tried:

```
type ('a, 'b) tree = Empty | Leaf of 'b | Node of ('a * tree ('a*'b))
```

and I was still getting an error.  Anything that you notice I was doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Turns out my syntax was just wrong. It should actually be

   Node ('a * ('a, 'b) tree)

Comment: That's right. It would be polite to accept gasche's answer though, since it does answer your question. I wonder if you're sure that you want distinct types for leaves and interiors nodes?

Answer (score 10):

```
type ('a, 'b) tree = Empty | Leaf of 'b | Node of 'a * ('a, 'b) tree
```

You probably want your Nodes two have more than one child, though

```
type ('a, 'b) tree = Empty | Leaf of 'b | Node of ('a, 'b) tree * 'a * ('a, 'b) tree
```

PS : Beware than in a type declaration, `Foo of bar * baz` and `Foo of (bar * baz)` are not the same : the first is a constructor `Foo` with two fields, the second has only one field, which is of type `(bar * baz)`.

Comment: Can you explain the impact of omitting the parenthesis in the constructor definition? I thought `bar * baz` was just a simpler way of defining tuples.